# ORA-00903: invalid table name when creating a new table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create the following table

```
create table asistenti
(
    marca Number(2) not null,
    nume Varchar2(30),
    prenume Varchar2(30),
    experienta Varchar2(30),
    marca_medic Number(2) not null,

    primary key (marca),

    foreign key(marca_medic) references to medici(marca)
);
```

But I get an error

> ORA-00903: invalid table name error

This is a new database, and I have created only one other table, `medici`

Comment: Is `marca` the primary key of `medici`? If it is not the foreign key reference will fail. If it is, why do you have have two tables with the same primary key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `to` in

```
references to medici(marca)
```